# Rabbitmq permissions

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I'm working with rabbitmq permissions with python. The application has multiple clients and one service provider. I want to limit clients to specific queues while service provider should be capable to read all queues and not write to any. I try to set permissions as follow:

For service provider account I have set the following

```
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p vhost service_provider ".*-client-queues" "" ".*-client-queues"
```

For clients I did

```
 rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p vhost client1 "client1-client-queues" "client1-client-queues" ""
```

And the message is never delivered to service provider. However, if I set

```
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p vhost client1 ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

it works. But I need to limit the clients to specific queues.
Does anyone of you try to achieve such thing? Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm missing is the exchange name while I set the permissions. I've solved my problem with the following permissions: (I'm using default exchange)

For clients:

```
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p vhost client1 "client1-client-queues|amq\.default" "client1-client-queues|amq\.default" "amq\.default"
```

For service provider:

```
set_permissions -p vhost service_provider ".*-client-queues|amq\.default" "amq\.default" ".*-client-queues|amq\.default"
```

Answer (score 2):

`service_provider` and `client1` must be the users that the respective components use instead of the default (`guest`) to connect to the RabbitMQ broker.

You need to create the users and set their passwords with `rabbitmqctl add_user ...`, then let the respective components use them.

Also note that the *exchanges* that you use to publish messages to, must match the write permission that you specify. See [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) for details.

I suggest you add the permissions one-by-one, so you see rapidly what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The users and queues are already created and I'm using default exchange. What I'm missing is the exchange name when I set the permissions. Once I added the default exchange while setting permissions, it works exactly the way I wanted. This is not exactly the answer I was looking for but you indeed helped me in finding out the answer. Thanks again!